# nodejs local agent functionality

Tags: node.js, sockets, local, agent

I have a website hosted on Heroku and Firebase (front (react) and backend(nodejs)) and I have some "long running scripts" that I need to perform. I had the idea to deploy a node process to my raspberry pi to execute this (because I need resources from inside my network).

How would I set this up securely?

I think I need to create a nodejs process that checks the central server regularly if there are any jobs to be done. Can I use sockets for this? What technology would you guys use?

I think the design would be:
1. Local agent starts and connects to server
2. Server sends messages to agent, or local agent polls with time interval

EDIT: I have multiple users that I would like to serve. The user should be able to "download" the agent and set it up so that it connects to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use firebase for this right? Create a new firebase db for "tasks" or whatever that is only accessible for you. When the central server (whatever that is) determines there's a job to be done, it adds it to your tasks db.

Then you write a simple node app you can run on your raspberry pi that starts up, authenticates with firebase, and listens for updates on your tasks database. When one is added, it runs your long running task, then removes that task from the database.

Wrap it up in a bash script that'll automatically run it again if it crashes, and you've got a super simple pubsub setup without needing to expose anything on your local network.

Comment: That is actually a good idea. I am struggling with one thing, however. I can use my admin credentials to access the nodejs admin client of firebase, but how would other users be able to connect their agent? Forgot to mention in the question that I have several users that should be able to deploy their agent in their network.

Comment: You can use custom claims to grant or limit access to db nodes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims
As long as you grant them access to the tasks list they can use their own credentials to authenticate.

Comment: But you cant programmatically create a custom claim? That is only valid for like 10 mins

Comment: I mean, I can give access to the tasks database, but how does an unattended agent use the credentials of the user? Custom tokens only last for like 10 mins.